# Cooking Parve food but with mixed utensils

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

If by mistake, someone who is cooking parve food but uses a dairy pot and selects a meat spatula or mixing utensil does this:
A) Raise concerns about the food
B) Render the pot non-kosher
C) Render the utensil non-kosher

This is assuming the food -such as eggs or a sauce were hot

-what is the status of the eggs is it still parve-dairy (I can eat it on a dairy plate).

The utensils in the specific case would have sat for 24 hours and been cleaned.

Comment: a good candidate to CYLOR.

Comment: (1.) Were the pot and spatula both completely clean from prior residue? (2.) Was one or both of them *ben yomo*? (3.) Was the ratio of the food to the volume of the part of the spatula inserted into the food more than 60:1? See [this article](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/kashrut/17kitchenaccidents.rtf).

Comment: how much time passed since the pot was last used? Is there 60 times more food than the surface volume of the spatula, immersed in it?

Comment: @gt6989b what is CYLOR?

Comment: @seekingclarity It stands for ["consult your local Orthodox rabbi"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR). In any event, the article I linked to above discusses your question and relevant sources.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50638

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99906/170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pot is Kosher. Spatula is Kosher. Eggs are Kosher. Note we are dealing here with a mistake, obviously *a priori* this should not be done.

1. According to the question, both the utensils were not used in 24 hours and were clean. Therefore, neither one can give out a taste sufficient to prohibit anything else. (Y.D. 94:4) Ergo, neither the pot or spatula require kashering, and the eggs may be eaten.
2. Eating the eggs in a dairy plate: more complicated, but essentially permitted as well. (Y.D. 95:1-2, Rema).

**Important:** if the eggs were made very spicy, or if onions were fried in the pan before the eggs were put in, that can completely change the din!