# Pareves made on dairy dishes and pareves made on meat dishes in the same meal

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Is it permissible to eat pareve food made on dairy equipment/dishes and pareve food made on meat equipment/dishes in the same meal/on the same plate?

Comment: possibly relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50638/759

Comment: … and especially the answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dispute whether one can eat parve food made on dairy equipment with meat (and vice-versa). Sefaradim tend to be lenient, Ashkenazim are strict from the outset (*lchathila*) and often lenient after the fact (*b'dieved*). A good summary of those laws can be found [here](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/788459/rabbi-avraham-gordimer/-d-e-dairy-equipment-certification-mysteries-and-facts/), a simpler one [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/milky-and-meaty-pots/) and the sefaradi view [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=503). Note it is always allowed to eat them one after the other - the question under debate is whether to eat them together.

But here you have parve food on dairy equipment with parve food on meat equipment on the same plate - which is a different case. I can see no reason why this should not be allowed under condition that the pots are clean, not used for 24 hours and that no hot/spicy foods are involved (e.g., onions, garlic, lemons, and pickles). I have now seen that R Yaakov Goldstein answers the same [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-status-of-pareve-foods-cooked-in-a-meat-pot-or-vice-versa/) and checked with R Binyamin Tabadi who concurs with the above.

> It is permitted to eat a Nat Bar Nat dairy food with a Nat Bar Nat
>   meat foods although one may not pour the content of either pot
>   directly into each other.

And of course, we are speaking only in theory here. Any application in real life would require consultation with your rabbi as small details can make a big difference.