# Can parve food cooked in dairy pot be served on a meaty plate?

Tags: meat-and-milk

Can parve food cooked in dairy pot be served on a meaty plate?

Note that the parve food is served chilled after it was refrigerated in a parve container.

EDIT:

The food is a parve drink with kosher dairy stamp, because it was packaged in a factory that also process dairy, there is a rigorous cleaning so there should not be any dairy in the process.

The plate is cold.

Comment: CYLOR..........

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.94.5 and https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.95.2

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50638/170 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28303

Comment: Not enough info given. Was there dairy in pot. If not, was the pot a bein yomo or not. Is the meaty plate hot ?

Comment: Yes. E even hot because of NAT BAR NAT. But there are many details in this Halacha. It's not recommended